# Facebook php sdk logout not working

Tags: php

Logout is not working and showing that page not found!!!     http://qclubiiti.eu5.org/dele.php  you can check it out here. When the user logs in it's fine but when he logs out it says that page not foud.

```
<?php
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');
/* USE NAMESPACES */

    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\GraphUser;
    use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
    use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
    use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
    use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
/*PROCESS*/

    //1.Stat Session
     session_start();
    //check if users wants to logout
     if(isset($_REQUEST['logout'])){
        unset($_SESSION['fb_token']);
     }

    //2.Use app id,secret and redirect url 
    $app_id = '*****************';
    $app_secret = '**********';
    $redirect_url='http://qclubiiti.eu5.org/dele.php';
    //3.Initialize application, create helper object and get fb sess
     FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
     $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
     $sess = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    //check if facebook session exists
    if(isset($_SESSION['fb_token'])){
        $sess = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['fb_token']);
    }
    //$logout = 'http://qclubiiti.eu5.org/dele2.php';
    $logout = 'http://qclubiiti.eu5.org/dele.php&logout=true';
    //4. if fb sess exists echo name 
        if(isset($sess)){
            //store the token in the php session
            $_SESSION['fb_token']=$sess->getToken();
            //create request object,execute and capture response
            $request = new FacebookRequest($sess,'GET','/me');
            // from response get graph object
            $response = $request->execute();
            $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::classname());
            // use graph object methods to get user details
            $name = $graph->getName();
            $id = $graph->getId();
            $image = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/picture?width=300';
            $email = $graph->getProperty('email');
            echo "hi $name <br>";
            echo "your email is $email <br><Br>";
            echo "<img src='$image' /><br><br>";
            echo "<a href='".$logout."'><button>Logoutto dele2</button></a>";
        }else{
            //else echo login
            echo '<a href="'.$helper->getLoginUrl(array('email')).'" >Login with facebook</a>';
        }
```

Comment: The query string part of a URL starts with a question mark, not an ampersand.

Comment: @CBroe It has worked. But the matter is that once I logout and login again I am able to directly enter without entering the password. Hwo can I resolve this? (I want that once I logout and login again, it should ask for my fb password again). Thanks a lot for your help....

Comment: That’s not how it’s supposed to work. As long as you are logged in to Facebook, showing the login dialog again will automatically redirect back to your app and have the user be logged in. Otherwise you will have to implement re-authentication: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication

Comment: Ok and thanks again for your help. I struggled for about a day on this issue.....